# How do i show that continuous maps between circles have the same degree iff they are homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let us consider two continuous maps $f,g:C\rightarrow C'$ where $C,C'$ are two circles. Show that they have the same degree iff they are homotopic.

> Def: Let $F:C\rightarrow C'$ be a continuous map and let $p'$ be the center of $C'$. Then we define $$deg(F)=W(F,p')$$ where $W$ is the winding number.

Here Is my definition of the winding number:

> [image]
> A sector at $p$ is the image of the following map $$S_{\Theta_1, \Theta_2}:Strip_{\Theta_1, \Theta_2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{p\};\,\,(r,\Theta)\mapsto p+(r\cos(\Theta),r\sin(\Theta))$$ where $Strip_{\Theta_1, \Theta_2}=\{(r,\Theta)|r>0, \Theta_1<\Theta<\Theta_2\}$ with $\Theta_1,\Theta_2\in [0,2\pi]$ and $0<\Theta_2-\Theta_1<2\pi$

What I remarked is that since any circle $C$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$, we can take $f,g:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ with out loss of generality. Now I wanted to assume that $f$ is homotopic to $g$. But we somehow never defined a homotopy between maps, only between loops and paths. What I know is that we always have the following picture:
[image]

Where $I=[a,b]$, $\gamma:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a continuous loop and $p$ is the center of $C$. Then we have $\phi(x)=p+r\cdot \left(\cos\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\cdot 2\pi\right),\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\cdot 2\pi\right)\right)$ where $r$ is the radius of $C$.

But now I somehow don't know where to start with the homotopy. Could someone maybe help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you familiar with covering spaces?

Comment: so it appears in the course but to be honest I couldn't look at it during the preparation time, so yes if you can help me using covering spaces it would be nice but I think you need to explain it in more details since I'm not into that topic yet

Comment: What is your definition of the winding number?

Comment: @PaulFrost I added a picture of our definition/construction

Comment: And what is the precise definition of a sector?

Comment: The definition of a sector is dissatisfactory. The is no sector at $p$ containing the horizontal ray $R = \{ p + t(1,0) \mid t > 0 \}$ starting at $p$ and going to the right. This comes from the assumption $\Theta_i \in [0,2\pi]$. No $\Theta$ between the $\Theta_i$ has the property $(\cos \Theta, \sin \Theta)) = (1,0)$. If you drop the assumption $\Theta_i \in [0,2\pi]$, then it will work.